# How do i acess to an item in a list sorted with tabulate in python?

Tags: python, list, replace, tabulate

the list name is "lavis" and i tried to acess to the item which contains "4" using lavis[0] but it did not work, (i used tabulate to display this)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: The first column does not contain the string "4".  It contains an integer `4`.  We need to see your code to figure out what you have here.

Comment: yes it contains an integer and yes i can send you the code but it's in french and contains almost 200 lines , it needs some time to understand